# How do I know if JID specified is already connected to the server?

Tags: c#, .net, xmpp, agsxmpp

I'm trying to find a solution to check if the user is logged in through the jid as a parameter, but without success.

I wonder if there is a way to check this without my having to log into the server. Before log verify that jid is already logged in and then treat with a message blocking access. I am using the agsXMPP library.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the presence via the JID directly from server without logging on. For example in open-fire :

http://example.com:9090/plugins/presence/status?jid=jsmith@example.com&type=xml

would give you back the user presence so you know he is online or not.

I do not believe the agxmpp sdk has any such method on its own.

Comment: How do I do that? Because when I call the method of checking the presence if the account is logged it is logged out. It checks the presence roste by the JID but this is handled in the public server, and methods of the protocol are asynchronous.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

I mean that anyone (anonymous) should be able to get public presence given a JID (configuration is of course needed on server side) and that would indicate if a user is online or offline. This is not 100% reliable because its always some delay in presence syndication if a user dropped for any other reason than a logoff.

Comment: Okay, but it happens that I wanted to check the user's presence without any login. EX: If you have an account X and want to log into the server but rather verifies that this account is already logged by someone else, if you are already logged back a notice saying that the account is already being used. What happens is that if I'm going to log in account X and already has another connected person, the server simply drops the connection established prior to authenticate my.

Comment: By doing this check before login I eliminate this problem in my application, but not completely because of external customers. This should be the rule server.
If you have any ideas, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918099/how-do-i-send-a-ping-to-a-user-xmpp-which-method-do-i-use